# Simple "plug'n'play" motor?

Tags: home-automation

I'm much more of a software guy than a hardware guy, but I'm looking to be able to control some blinds (inexpensively). I think I'm looking for a stepper motor (as in it can turn any number of rotations (unlike a servo?), and will hold it's position (without power or without input?).

Based on this sketchy idea of needing a stepper motor [this one](http://www.modmypi.com/electronics/motors-and-robotics/stepper-motor-4-wire-200-steps-rev-12v-400ma) seems up for the task. But I have no idea how I'd go about connecting it to the Pi, and can't really find any instructions for doing so.

Is there a simple motor that can be bought that just plugs into the raspberry pi? That won't require chips/resistors/soldering wires?

Answer (score 1):

A stepper motor can rotate continuously, unlike most servos.

As far as I am aware a stepper won't hold its position against an opposing force without power.  The power through the coils is needed for a stepper to maintain its torque.

You need some sort of motor driver board for a stepper.  Simplest would be something based on a ULN2003A or equivalent, or perhaps a L9110S.  A bulkier alternative would be a board based on the L298N.  You will need to make sure that the solution you opt for can handle the desired voltages and current.

A Pi can not drive a motor directly.  The GPIOs are rated for 3V3 and a few milliamps, nowhere near enough to drive a motor.  The GPIOs can drive a motor driver board.

Typically for a bi-polar stepper you connect 4 GPIOs to 4 pins on the driver board and then pulse the stepper by setting the GPIOs high and low in a defined pattern.  There are plenty of examples on the www.

The only motor you can drive directly from the Pi is a servo, simple because a servo generally has an in-built motor driver board.

Google for Raspberry Pi blind control.  It seems to be a fairly popular project.

Comment: I have googled for Raspberry Pi blind control, but it either comes up with Arduino projects or ones that use tubular motors that cost $100+

Comment: I'd look through the Arduino projects for inspiration.  Look for the motors they use and how they are driven.  There are two basic differences between the Pi and the Arduino.  Most Arduinos have 5V GPIOs and Arduinos have in-built ADC converters.  Both have generally simple solutions.